# How to detect malfunction in motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, cpu-cooler

If you are not sure whether a motherboard has been damaged, if it boots then is that 100% verification it is alright?

Comment: Just linked as was asked to..But query still remains

Comment: No.  Just because it boots doesn't mean there cannot be damage.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of the suggested question.

Comment: It may be a duplicate but to be honest the answer has no been ticked...And yeah just because it boots it does not mean it is 100%. It may cut out whilst in use...some slots may not be working!!

Comment: Things are rarely that simple in the real world. Computer damage does not follow any set of rules as to the problems it can cause. There are many types of damage that would not prevent bootup. And then there are intermittents.

Comment: @LMiller7 well, it does follow rules, but they are complex and for most of us, inscrutable.

Answer (score 1):

A booting computer is not verification that the motherboard is working at 100%.  However, it is a *very good* sign that it is.

Since you tagged `CPU Cooler`, I am guessing you put a cooler on and flexed the motherboard more than you feel comfortable.  Motherboards do have some flex in them, but there is no measurable way to say when is good or not.  It is entirely possible during the flex, that a trace was cracked.  In my experience, I have never seen this happen though.

Some computers have diagnostics on boot, which stress different components on the motherboard and give a report.  Sadly, this is not a common option.  The best test would be to simply use the computer.  If something critical was broken, you would likely notice problems very quickly.  This could be blue screens, freezing, power outages, etc.